# What is this bone from?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, bone-biology, bone

This object showed up on my fire escape in New York city. It appears to be some kind of bone. It's a bit smaller than an adult human hand. What animal is it from?

[image: bone picture]

[image: bone with inches]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Given the size and thin/elongated [ilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilium_(bone)) as well as the urban location, I think a **domestic cat** and/or a raccoon are likely candidates. I'm leaning toward cat.

**Cat pelvis:**

[image]

<sup>[VCA Hospitals](https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/femoral-head-ostectomy-fho-in-cats)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Ventral view of domestic cat pelvis; Source: [BoneID](http://www.boneid.net/product/ventral-view-domestic-cat-pelvis/)</sup>

**Raccoon Pelvis**

[image]

<sup>Anterior view of raccoon pelvis; Source: [BoneID](http://www.boneid.net/product/anterior-view-raccoon-pelvis/)</sup>

I'm not an expert in differentiating these two species' bones. I will note that your specimen is more or less in between the sizes of these two species. Your size is probably closer to the raccoon, but a cat is just more likely given the location.

The most noticeable trait that stands out to me is the size/pointedness of the [ischial tuberosity](http://bio.sunyorange.edu/updated2/comparative_anatomy/anat_3/hip_files/hip_monk.jpg), which better matches that of the cat.

Comment: I could not for the life of me definitely identify it from the first picture alone. I saw those sockets and thought "hips", and those articulations and thought, vertebrae, but I never saw such a pelvis. This is why you have a gold badge in identification. Fantastic!

Comment: @anongoodnurse, teaching 11 years of anatomy + that arduous comparative vert anatomy course I took all those years ago in college help a lot :p.

Comment: I'm still in awe. Makes me want to take a comparative vert anatomy course!